# No numpy.lib in fresh Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-3.5

I have a script using numpy and didn't have numpy inside of my virtual machine. I went ahead and ran...

```
$ sudo apt install python3-pip python3-dev python3-wheel
$ sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
$ sudo -H pip3 install numpy
```

... to get numpy installed. When I ran my script, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
ImportError: No module named 'numpy.lib'
```

I have never see this `numpy.lib` business before. My script works on other machines without any errors.

I ran `pip show numpy` which tells me numpy is at version 1.13.1.

Where is this `numpy.lib` and/or how can I get past this error? Should I install an older version of numpy? I'm used to Python working out of the box, so this is new to me.

Thanks!

---

- Linux Mint 18 x64 (inside of VirtualBox running on Windows 7)
- Python 3.5.2

Comment: Maybe you should install numpy without sudo. As it will install it to root user but not current user. Try `pip3 install numpy`

Comment: That does not help. And I'm pretty sure if it was a permissions issue, I'd see an error at `import numpy` not later, internal to numpy, in this `add_newdocs.py` file. I did try it, nonetheless. Using `pip`, uninstalled and reinstalled. Didn't work until I `chown`d the `dist-packages` directory to my username. Anyway, same result (still get `numpy.lib` import error). This didn't fix it.

Comment: You should find a directory named `lib` located at `/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/`. If you don't, your numpy was installed with some issues.

Comment: Yes I do find it. `cd /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages` and then `grep -rn "def add_newdoc" shows `lib/function_base.py:4514:def add_newdoc(place, obj, doc):` so I would think the install went just fine.

Comment: Whoops, just realized I wasn't looking at the directory you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Sraw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5588279/sraw), I believe I've arrived at a solution.

Their note about checking the `.local` directory in my home folder got me  poking around some more and I found that running `pip3 install <package>` was installing to `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages` and not `$HOME/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages`

To fix this, I first uninstalled the packages I was attempting to install (in this case, `numpy`) with

`$ pip3 uninstall <package>`

Then, I followed the [numpy install instructions here](https://www.scipy.org/install.html). Specifically, I ran these two commands:

```
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
$ python3 -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
```

To test, I enter the python REPL with `python3` and type `import numpy`. No errors. Then I ran my script mentioned in the question. Again, no errors. Works as expected.

Thank you to Sraw for helping me solve this issue. I appreciate it!